# SQL Pull rows where there is a 25% decrease in one column within 72 hours (another column has dates)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
#   patient_ID  Performed_date      Admit_date  Discharge_date  Result  rn
1   1       8/26/18 10:20 AM    8/25/2018   8/30/2018   30  1
2   1       8/27/18 11:40 AM    8/25/2018   8/30/2018   30  2
3   1       8/28/18 8:30 AM     8/25/2018   8/30/2018   30  3
4   1       8/29/18 9:50 AM     8/25/2018   8/30/2018   10  4
5   1       8/30/18 5:40 AM     8/25/2018   8/30/2018   10  5
6   4       3/9/17 11:20 AM     3/9/2017    3/10/2017   37  1
7   4       3/10/17 7:36 AM     3/9/2017    3/10/2017   15  2
8   4       4/13/18 8:30 AM     4/13/2018   4/20/2018   20  1
9   4       4/14/18 8:30 AM     4/13/2018   4/20/2018   5   2
10  4       4/15/18 7:10 AM     4/13/2018   4/20/2018   30  3
11  4       4/16/18 9:40 AM     4/13/2018   4/20/2018   10  4
12  4       4/17/18 8:40 AM     4/13/2018   4/20/2018   10  5
```

Sample data

For each row I want to compare the result number against all previous values that happen within 72 hours of the performed_date column. And I want it to be compared within groups based on patient_id and admit date (ie for each stay)

For example row 2 would be compared against row 1, row 3 would be compared against row 2 and row 1, row 4 would be compared against rows 1, 2 and 3, and row 5 would be compared against row 2, 3 and 4.

The rows that should return would be rows 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12.

Comment: . . I get that you are comparing something.  I'm not sure exactly what and how the comparison affects the results.

Comment: so I want it to pull the rows where the result column has a 25% or more decrease in it's value. ie for row 5 since the value is 10 and the row 3 the value was 30 (and it was within 72 horus) there was a 66% decrease so the code should pull row 5.